# Why I'm allowed to assign a new address to a vector containing constant pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants

I think the title is clear on explaining my problem.... consider the following snippet:

```
class Critter {
    int m_Age;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Critter* const> critters;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        critters.push_back(new Critter());

    critters[2] = new Critter();

    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the line `critters[2] = new Critter();` be illegal?

Thank You

Comment: This is why providing compilable examples is a good idea. The code you provide does not compile (even after adding #include <vector> and make vector into std::vector). So either you are doing something slightly different than we expect or you did not cut and paste the code (or both)

Comment: It does indeed compile with MSVC. An implementation bug?

Comment: From what I can see there isn't any requirement in the standard to diagnose an error if the type you use in a container violates a constraint that it must meet. Given this, I think you just get undefined behaviour so if it compiles that doesn't mean it's an implementation bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this line should be illegal (even given `#include <vector>` and `using std::vector;`):

```
vector<Critter* const> critters;
```

Because it is a requirement for a type to be used in a container to be assignable and anything that is `const` clearly isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't post the entire code because what's missing are only the includes and using... anyway here is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Critter {
    int m_Age;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Critter* const> critters;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        critters.push_back(new Critter());

    critters[2] = new Critter();

    return 0;
}
```

And this code as it is, compiles fine, even without a warning in VS 2010...
Thanks once more...